# PHP foreach get iteration index

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to display results in a `foreach` loop.

I have an array like so:

```
$slides = array(
    1 => $params->get('param_1'), 
    2 => $params->get('param_2'),
    3 => $params->get('param_3')
);
```

If a parameter in the backend is set to **yes**, the value equals **1**, and thus a result is displayed.

So what I'm trying to write is, `foreach` array value that is equal to **1**

I'm aware that I **can't** use something like this:

```
foreach (slides == 1) { 
    // echo stuff here
}
```

How would I write this `foreach` loop? Any help or guidelines would be highly appreciated

Comment: The issue here is not the `foreach` loop at all. You *want* to iterate over each element. The issue is to test the value of each item in the array and only if it answers a certain condition, then you output it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ( $slides as $slide ) { 
    if ( $slide != 1 ) continue;
    // echo stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, this works perfectly. I'll accept when it allows me to